# BufferedImage Colour Manipulation

Tags: java, colors, rgb, bufferedimage

I'm currently working on an application that requires the changing of certain colors in a BufferedImage. (For example Black to Red)

I've noticed some strange behaviour when using the setRGB method of the BufferedImage class.

Unless the specified RGB value has already features somewhere in the image, the setRGB will simply set it to a completely transparent pixel.

The obvious workaround is to have all the desired colors in the image, but can anybody explain to me why this happens, or how to fix it? Thanks.

```
public Texture replaceColour(final TextureColour TARGET, final TextureColour REPLACEMENT)
{
            /*
             * You needn't worry about this bit, just some checks my program
             * uses to determine if a similar image has already been created.
             */
    final String PATH = loadedTexturesFilenames.get(REFERENCE) + "!replacedColour:" + TARGET.RGB + ":" + REPLACEMENT.RGB;
    final Texture PATH_TEXTURE = getTexture(PATH);
    if (PATH_TEXTURE == null)
    {
                    /*
                     * This is where the color changing happens.
                     * See below for information on the 'Texture' and
                     * 'TextureColour' classes.
                     */
        final BufferedImage IMAGE = cloneImage(BUFFERED_IMAGE);
        for (int x = 0; x != IMAGE.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y != IMAGE.getHeight(); y++)
            {
                if (getColour(x, y) == TARGET)
                {
                    IMAGE.setRGB(x, y, REPLACEMENT.RGB);
                }
            }
        }
        return new Texture(IMAGE, PATH);
    }
    else
    {
        return PATH_TEXTURE;
    }
}

public static BufferedImage cloneImage(final BufferedImage I) 
{
     ColorModel colour = I.getColorModel();
     boolean alpha = colour.isAlphaPremultiplied();
     WritableRaster writableRaster = I.copyData(null);
     return new BufferedImage(colour, writableRaster, alpha, null);
}
```

Some notes on the code:

- The 'Texture' class is used by my program to store BufferedImages 'efficiently'.
- The following methods are within the Texture class.
- The 'TextureColour' class stores an RGB value that has been generated using getRGB(x, y) on another BufferedImage containing colours. It's done this way to avoid confusion on RGB values and to allow colours to be changed without code changes.
- The getColour(x, y) message returns the 'TextureColour' according to the results given by the BufferedImage.getRGB(x, y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that the image is using an indexed color model, and so only colors that are already present in the image can be drawn. Try creating the cloned image with TYPE_INT_ARGB. Something like:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(I.getWidth(), I.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
//draw original image I to the new graphics
g.dispose();
return image;
```

I hope this solves your problem, it's hard to reproduce it locally without your image data...

Answer (score 1):

Note that [the documentation for setRGB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29) points out that "For images with an IndexColorModel, the index with the nearest color is chosen."

In your wrapper classes, is there any way that your BufferedImages might be of an indexed type? If so, you may want to create a new BufferedImage from the existing one with the type TYPE_INT_ARGB instead of an indexed type before manipulating it.